# Allocate memory for multiple pointer of struct recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, calloc

How I can to allocate memory recursively for a struct?

Currently I allocate memory for each members but is a lot of code and I lock for a better method.

```cpp
struct A {
   long *a1;
   bool *a2;
}

struct B {
   int* b1;
   double* b2;
}

struct C {
   A* a;
   B* b;
}
```

Is there a method to recursively allocate memory for structure C?

Comment: Why are you using ponters?  If you want those member to be arrays, switch to using `std::vector`, it will handle all the memory management for you.  If they are not going to point to arrays, they should not be pointers.

Comment: It is a generated code. I can not change that.

Comment: What do you mean by recursive allocation? What are you allocating?

Comment: Yes, there is a method in C++ to recursively allocate memory for struct objects.  However, because you said "It is a generated code. I can not change that." you won't be able to use it.  You'll need to make factory functions to do the allocations on behalf of the structs.